# Convert a double in the format ab,cdef to 'ab', 'cd', and 'ef' in adjacent cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

What is the best formula to use in Excel in order to convert a double in the format ab,cdef to 'ab', 'cd', and 'ef' in adjacent cells?

Example:

```
2,6059 --> 2   60  59   
10,315 --> 10  31  50
```

Comment: What "best" means for you? Fastest / shortest / easiest to understand? What have you already tried? Why that didn't work for you?

Comment: just some method to get this done, I solved this with a java script, and would like to know how to do it with Excel, no big deal

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways to do it, depending on your needs.

You can get at the digits using arithmetic. I assume the number is in A1, and the following formula's are in B1-D1.

```
=FLOOR(A1,1)
=FLOOR(A1*10^2,1)-B1*10^2
=FLOOR(A1*10^4,1)-10^4*B1-10^2*C1
```

Alternatively, you could manipulate the number as a text string. Put the following formula's in F1-I1

```
=TEXT(A1,"00.0000")
=MID(F1,1,2)
=MID(F1,4,2)
=MID(F1,6,2)
```